# Error on base.net size with networkDynamic

Tags: r, network-programming

I am having an issue trying to create a temporal network of judicial precedents. I have coded several instances of cases citing other cases (which leads to a DAG). I fave followed [this tutorial](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/temporal-network-analysis-with-r) and succeeded with a previous version of the database. But when my team and I expanded it, the old code gives the following error:

```
  base.net network size is smaller than size implied by vertex.ids in vertex or edge argument
```

I have no problem creating the network and visualizing it as a network object. Here's the description I get after I do that.

```
 Network attributes:
  vertices = 414 
  directed = TRUE 
  hyper = FALSE 
  loops = FALSE 
  multiple = FALSE 
  bipartite = FALSE 
  total edges= 1271 
    missing edges= 0 
    non-missing edges= 1271 

 Vertex attribute names: 
    color instancia nombre_caso quarter_onset tribunal vertex.id vertex.names 

 Edge attribute names not shown
```

But when I try to add temporal data, I get the previous mistake. Here's a link to the `dynamic_nodes.csv` [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramiroau/temporal_precedents/main/dynamic_nodes.csv) and the `dynamic_edges.csv` [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramiroau/temporal_precedents/main/dynamic_edges.csv). I am stuck because the base.net network size is 414, exactly the number of vertex.ids that I have in `dynamic_nodes`. I even checked to see it the `tail` and `head` ids in the `dynamic_edges` file do not match `vertex.id`, but they do.

Any ideas on how might I proceed to deal with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question. I was using R version 4.0.2 and went back to version 3.6 and the error dissappeared. I also run the code in a different system with version 4.0.0 and the error also dissappeared.